# Gift Aid reports

Tags: civireport

Is anyone aware of any guidance for running a report within Civi for a UK HMRC Gift Aid claim please? I am not a techy person, but a user of Civi for financial reporting for our organisation. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an extension which can do this for you: https://docs.civicrm.org/ukgiftaid/en/latest/submission/

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM.SE. It's good practice on StackExchange to provide a short summary of the information behind a link, rather than simply posting a URL, as links tend to go stale. I encourage you to look through https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for additional tips.